# Load different initial view based on application preferences?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have a preference that, when set, forces my application to perform some synchronization on startup.

Can I use IB to display a different initial view based on this setting?

Is there a standard way to enable this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a property on your app delegate that is set during your synchronization, in the initial view controller's initWithNibNamed: method check the value synced by the app delegate and load the appropriate nib by calling `[super initWithNibNamed:@"thisNibInsteadOfThatNib"];`

**EDIT:** Show code to launch a different view depending on some condition at launch

```
// AppDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window;
    UIViewController *firstViewController;
}
@property {nonatomic, retain} UIWindow *window;
@end

// AppDelegate.m
#import AppDelegate.h
#import ViewControllerOne.h
#import ViewControllerTwo.h

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    BOOL shouldLoadViewOne = \\ some value from preferences

    if (shouldLoadViewOne) {
        firstViewController = [[ViewOneController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewOneController" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        firstViewController = [[ViewTwoController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewTwoController" bundle:nil];
    }

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

    [window addSubView:[navController view]];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Make use of `NSClassFromSting()` and save the name of the firstViewController to load in the preferences.

```
// AppDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window;
    id firstViewController;
}
@property {nonatomic, retain} UIWindow *window;

- (NSString *)firstViewControllerName;

@end

// AppDelegate.m
#import AppDelegate.h
#import ViewControllerOne.h
#import ViewControllerTwo.h

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSString *viewControllerName = [self firstViewControllerName];

    firstViewController = [[NSClassFromString(viewControllerName) alloc] initWithNibName:viewControllerName  bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

    [window addSubView:[navController view]];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (NSString *)firstViewControllerName
{
    NSString *defaultViewController = @"ViewOneController";
    NSString *savedFirstViewController = // string retrieved from preferences or other persistent store

    if (!savedFirstViewController)
        return defaultViewController;

    return savedFirstViewController;
}
```

Comment: alternatively, if you have different view controllers for each nib ( ViewOneController, ViewTwoController) initialize the the controller or the view that you need to load based on the condition from the sync in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

Comment: of course this assumes that this isn't an "internationalization" question which is handled automatically at runtime if you create the necessary nib files as per Apple documentation

Comment: Can you please elaborate on initializing 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'?

Comment: updated answer to show loading a different rootView depending on some condition.

Comment: Added another alternative using NSClassFromString()

Comment: That's excellent, man. I really appreciate the great code! Your second example is really helpful too.